# Found extra flags error in new version of protractor

Tags: node.js, npm, protractor

I am trying to run a js scripts using protractor, but i am getting following error

```
C:\Users\Hoodi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\cli.js:172
        throw new Error('Found extra flags: ' + unknownKeys.join(', '));
        ^

Error: Found extra flags: identityManagement
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Hoodi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\cli.js:172:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Hoodi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\bin\protractor:5:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
```

My config file

```
// conf.js
exports.config = {
  framework: 'jasmine',
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  useAllAngular2AppRoots: true,

  // Options to be passed to Jasmine-node.
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    // Use colors in the command line report.
    showColors: true,

    // Default time to wait in ms before a test fails.
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 60000,
  },

  onPrepare: function() {
      require('../../lib/waitReady.js');
  },

  capabilities :{
      browserName : 'chrome',
  }
}

console.dir("argv: " + process.argv)

switch(process.argv[3]) {
    case '--identityManagement':
        exports.config.specs = ['./identityManagement.js'];
        break;
    default:
        exports.config.specs = ['./identityManagement.js'];
}
```

I tried executing above script using protractor as well as "npm run" command, but in both cases i am getting same error. command that i used

```
protractor ./conf.js --identityManagement
```

and

```
npm run im
```

This actually works on my other system. npm and node version of system where this works are

```
node v7.2.1
npm  v3.10.10
```

And where is doesnt work

```
node v7.4.0
npm  v4.0.5
```

My package.json file looks like this

```
{
  "name": "intelliflash",
  "author": "Vishwanath Rawat <rawat@tegile.com>",
  "description": "IntelliFlash tests",
  "scripts": {
    "im": "protractor ./conf.js --identityManagement"
  }
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 5):

It has nothing to do with your npm or node versions, Latest release of **Protractor 5.0** has put a check in cli for **unidentified flags** as you are putting with the help of process.argv.

You can solve this by disabling the flag checks:

```
 protractor ./conf.js --identityManagement --disableChecks
```

For more details please refer the Protractor 5.0 [changelog](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#500)

**Note:** min node version now is v6.9.x which supports this version of protractor